# In Python, how can I print a dictionary containing large numbers without an 'L' being inserted after the large numbers?

Tags: string, dictionary, python-2.7, long-integer, repr

I have a dictionary as follows

```
d={'apples':1349532000000, 'pears':1349532000000}
```

Doing either str(d) or repr(d) results in the following output

```
{'apples': 1349532000000L, 'pears': 1349532000000L}
```

How can I get str, repr, or print to display the dictionary without it adding an L to the numbers?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the `L` suffix denotes a 64-bit integer.  Without it, those numbers are 32-bit integers.  Those numbers don't fit into 32 bits because they are too large.  If the `L` suffix was omitted, the result would not be valid Python, and the whole point of `repr()` is to emit valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a little embarrasing, I just found a solution after quite a few attempts :-P

One way to do this (which suits my purpose) is to use json.dumps() to convert the dictionary to a string.

```
d={'apples':1349532000000, 'pears':1349532000000}

import json
json.dumps(d)
```

Outputs

```
'{"apples": 1349532000000, "pears": 1349532000000}'
```